# Sending a POST request to the server

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat, post

I need to send a `POST` request using java. The server i am trying to access has a username and password i need to pass those parameters as well.

1.) I have installed Tomcat in my machine and configured the developer environment. I am using eclipse. There are different types of projects i could create using Eclipse, and i need to know what is the best project i should create to develop my application ?

2.) Can someone show me some sample code or tutorial which would help me to develop my task ?

My Eclipse version : Eclipse Java EE, Indigo service release 2

**EDIT**

Is it a JPA project, Enterprise Application Project, Dynamic Web Project, Dynamic Web Application, EJB project, Application Client project, Static Web Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna create a website use "dynamic web project"

for your issue, this might be useful:
[Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

Answer (score 1):

You should create Web project.
[image]

http://besthowtodo.com/blog/2010/05/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse.html

Comment: Note that the suggestion is to choose "Dynamic Web Project" as seen in the (completely unnecessary) screenshot, while this answer says only "Web project" and there are several choices that could be construed as "web project".

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Web project should be the option you must select for performing this.
In eclipse you can do this by following the steps as mentioned in the below link

[http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcreprj.html](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/twcreprj.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this link.. Hope will be helpful to you..

Please read the link till point 20. Once you know how to write a web-service, we can arrange a training session with Shivang on how to integrate webservices with Appian.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Comment: You just mentioned something about a training session. you entered it by mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial in PDF from [Core Servlets](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/csajsp2/03-Form-Data.pdf) 
Another [Tutorial](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) from Core Servlets